# Synchronous external JS loading with zombie.js

Tags: javascript, zombie.js

The problem:

I'm using zombie.js to test my client-side javascript, but I am running into a problem. Zombie.js does not provide synchronous `<script>` tag execution, and, in fact seems to not execute external JS files at all. A basic test confirms this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   console.log("Inline javascript.");
</script>
```

Each test#.js contains a single line: `console.log("TEST#.JS");`

When I render this in a regular browser, the console displays the expected:

```
TEST1.JS
TEST2.JS
TEST3.JS
Inline javascript.
```

But when I run it with zombie.js, I only see a single line `Inline javascript.`

Here's what I have tried to get around the issue:

1. using `document.createElement` to dynamically append a script tag to the document
2. using `document.write` to add the script block into the html
3. using a `setTimeout` on `console.log("Inline javascript")` in combination with 1 and 2 to give the test scripts some time to load.

Is there any way to resolve this issue, besides placing the JS code from all my external JS files into a huge `<script>` block?

Comment: Have you considered PhantomJS as an alternative to Zombie?

Comment: Yeah, I started out with PhantomJS, but there are several bugs that (i.e. navigator.onLine is always false, etc.) that made me move away from it.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the browser object has the "runScripts" option set to true? If not you can use the following syntax:

```
browser.visit('... your page url ...', { runScripts: true }, function (e, b) { 
    console.log('executing callback'); 
});
```